# Xamarin Studio 6.2 Drag & Drop disappears after couple of seconds - AXML Bug only

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Whenever I'm trying to Drag & Drop an element into the designer view, or even to the Document Outline, the element seems to disappear after one to two seconds after dragging it.

It starts to shrink the preview of that element and after it is fully shrinked, then it disappears immediately. The bug/problem doesn't exist on the Xamarin Studio 6.0, But that version seems to crash a lot.

[This is a screen share of what happens. (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9i59wz82kpxcpr/Recording%20%231.mp4?dl=0)

[Log files. (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/r5V4Shhv)

Comment: Submit a bug: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: @SushiHangover https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53006